# Oracle Rebus Queue Expiration and Visible TimeStamps UTC instead of local

Tags: rebus

We are using the Oracle Rebus package but all datetimes we use are UTC. Is it possible to have the Oracle Rebus Queue column Expiration and Visible in UTC timestamp instead of local?

We use the following packages:

- Rebus Version="6.3.1"
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core Version="2.18.3"
- Rebus.Serilog Version="6.0.0"
- Rebus.ServiceProvider Version="5.0.6"

Comment: Could you maybe update your question with more information about which packages you're using? Something tells me this is about the Rebus.SqlServer transport, but it would be nice if you'd be more specific.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand Rebus' Oracle transport correctly, the timestamps are represented using the Oracle DB type "TimeStampTZ", which means that they're representations of unambiguous instants on the global timeline (which just happen to carry along information about the offset from UTC with which they were captured).

This means that they're basically UTC timestamps that just happen to be offset by a timespan.

So my question is this: Why would it help you to have them stored at UTC timestamps?

Doesn't Oracle automatically compare the UTC times of timestamps so that e.g. '2021-02-28T19:36:00+01:00' = '2021-02-28T18:36:00Z' ?

Comment: Functional it works but visually it is strange that we have other tables in the Oracle DB that have e.g.  '2021-02-28T18:36:00Z' and in the Queue table we have  '2021-02-28T19:36:00+01:00'. From an IT administrator perspective it is strange and can lead to analysis mistakes. It would be great if you could set a Rebus option for the timestamps notation in either UTC or local.

Comment: Well ok  happy that it works for you, but unfortunately no – it's currently not configurable